# Find the average of three random numbers

Tags: java, random, average

I am trying to generate three random integers between 0 and 50, calculate the average, and print the result. 
This is what I have so far:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package random.numbers;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author ericl_000
 */
public class RandomNumbers {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Random rand = new Random ();
        int RandNum = 0;

        for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            RandNum = rand.nextInt(50);
            System.out.println(RandNum);
        }

        int average = (RandNum);
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

**The output has the 3 random numbers, but the average is the last number of those 3 numbers. I don't know how to get the average of these 3 numbers. (I am new with Java.)**

Comment: Let's forget Java for a second.  How would you calculate the average on a piece of paper?  Because I'm not seeing any attempt at calculating an average in the code...

Comment: You may want to use `double` instead of `int`. What's the average of {43, 44, 44}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for calculating average is not correct, logic for average is:

```
average = (num1+num2+num3+... .... +num N)/N
```

So your logic for code should be:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int RandNum = 0;
float average = 0;

for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    RandNum = rand.nextInt(50);
    System.out.println(RandNum);
    average = average+RandNum;
}

average = average/3;
System.out.println(average);
```

Comment: Only problem is most averages aren't exact integers

Answer (score 0):

The average formula is the sum of all the numbers in a list divided by number by the number of items in that list. You can do this by constantly adding the random numbers up into a variable, lets call it x, then divide that by 3 (total number of items in that list).

```
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    RandNum = rand.nextInt(50);
    System.out.println(RandNum);
    int x += RandNum; //the += sign adds the current value of x to the value of RandNum
}

int average = (x/3);
System.out.println(average);
```

This answer assumes that you will be only using 3 random numbers.This is using ints however you should probably use doubles considering most averages aren't exact integers:

```
double RandNum = 0;
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    RandNum = rand.nextDouble(50);
    System.out.println(RandNum);
    double x += RandNum; //the += sign adds the current value of x to the value     of RandNum
}

double average = (x/3);
System.out.println(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = 0, total = 0;
        int count = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // This gives you 0 to 49, does not include 50!
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(50);
            System.out.println(randomNum);

            // Keep track of total
            total += randomNum;
        }

        // Average is well, total divided by count
        int average = total / count;
        System.out.printf("Average (Integer division): %d%n", average);

        // Using double
        double averageDouble = total / ((double) count);
        System.out.printf("Average (Double division): %7.3f%n", averageDouble);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
26
8
Average (Integer division): 12
Average (Double division):  12.333
```

**Note:**

- Using integer or double for division will give u different results!
- [random#nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) gives you a value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), i.e. `nextInt(50)` will give you 0 to 49.

Answer (score 0):

and how would you compute the average in real life? You add the numbers up, and you divide by 3.

```
int sum=0;
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
   sum += rand.nextInt(50);
System.out.println(sum/3.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the random numbers as they are generated.

```
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    RandNum = rand.nextInt(50);
    System.out.println(RandNum);
}
```

For each iteration of the loop, a random number is generated and printed.
But is nowhere saved.Then how can you access them later to calculate the average.
Try something like this

```
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    RandNum += rand.nextInt(50);
}
```

This will add generated random number to already generated one.So bascially
RandNum will contain the sum at the end of all iterations of the loop.

Then you can use the following to print the average.

```
System.out.println(RandNum/3);
```

Just by naming a variable 'average', it wont find the average.You have to 
do the necessary calculation.ie.(sum/n).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is a complicated problem.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random ();
    int randCount = 3, randNum = 0, total = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < randCount; i++) {
        randNum = rand.nextInt(50);
        System.out.println(randNum);
        total = total + randNum;
    }

    int average = total/randCount;
    System.out.println(average);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int RandNum = 0;


int[] numbers = new int[]{rand.nextInt(50),rand.nextInt(50),rand.nextInt(50)};

            double sum = 0; 

for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}

            for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
                    sum = sum + numbers[i];
            double average = sum / numbers.length;
            System.out.println("Average value of array elements is : " + average);


    }
    }
```